# cx_Freeze MSI error

Tags: python, windows-installer, cx-freeze

I have successfully compiled my python file to cx_Freeze, but when I click on the application I get the following error:

[error image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haBx7.jpg)

Here is my `setup.py`:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

company_name = 'Vagif Programs'
product_name = 'BananaCell'

bdist_msi_options = {
    'upgrade_code': '{66620F3A-DC3A-11E2-B341-002219E9B01E}',
    'add_to_path': False,
    'initial_target_dir': r'[ProgramFilesFolder]\%s\%s' % (company_name, 
product_name),
    }

build_exe_options = {
    'includes': ['tkinter', 'tkinter.filedialog', 'openpyxl.utils'],
    }


base = None
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'


exe = Executable(script='comparing.py',
                 base=base,
                 icon='icon.ico',
                 shortcutName='BananaCell',
                 shortcutDir='DesktopFolder'
                )



setup(name=product_name,
      version='1.0.0',
      description='blah',
      executables=[exe],
      options={
          'bdist_msi': bdist_msi_options,
          'build_exe': build_exe_options})
```

Can anyone help me? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please ensure 'comparing.py' running without  any error.

Comment: @KarthikeyanKR yes comparing.py works without any error

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, something goes wrong on line 1 of `comparing.py`. Specifically, Python cannot find something called `_fix_up_module`.

If your script (`comparing.py`) normally works without error when you run it prior to packaging, then the error is likely caused by some dependency not being included with the executable you have built. If this dependency is a module, then you need to declare it in your `setup.py` using something like the `include_files` option.

https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup_script.html

### include_files

> list containing files to be copied to the target directory; it is expected that this list will contain strings or 2-tuples for the source and destination; the source can be a file or a directory (in which case the tree is copied except for .git, .svn and CVS directories); the target must not be an absolute path